# How to return rows that contain a numbers or decimals

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g

I have a `VARCHAR` column called `description` in the table `test_table`. How do I only return rows that contain a number or decimal number in the `description` column?

So for example these would be considered valid rows to return:

- `I love the number 3424`
- `434 is cool`
- `when can 23 be the best age`
- `My sweet16today`
- `when there is 0.143secs left`
- `I love 0.314 because its pi`

As long as there is any number in the description, its considered a valid row to return.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bracket wildcards](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) that search for only numbers.

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE description LIKE '%[1234567890]%';
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov what was the error?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. It just doesn't work. I think because its actually searching for the `[1234567890]` character and not treating it like a set

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Im not a fan of this solution, but you can use OR statements to seperate each digit. The query would be very long but im positive it would work. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: "Bracket wildcard" may exist in other database products like MS Access, but in Oracle they only exist in regular expression functions and comparisons. The answer is wrong for Oracle database; one of the downvotes is from me, since the answer is completely not helpful to anyone with the same question in Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

`^[[:digit:]]+$` will match strings with numeric characters only (no non-numeric characters). You should use `'[[:digit:]]+'` or `[0-9]`.